# WSGI Python adapter to test FastCGI: Error starting WSGI server

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, fastcgi, httpd.conf, mod-python

When I'm trying to run the WSGI Python script to test FastCGI from this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#setting-up-fastcgi):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from cgi import escape
import sys, os
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])

    yield '<h1>FastCGI Environment</h1>'
    yield '<table>'
    for k, v in sorted(environ.items()):
         yield '<tr><th>%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>' % (escape(k), escape(v))
    yield '</table>'

WSGIServer(app).run()
```

It results in following, from the error log it isn't clear what went wrong based on the returned app status 0. It could be that I am missing something.

```
Mod_python error: "PythonHandler mod_python.publisher"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 398, in HandlerDispatch
    result = obj(req)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 213, in handler
    module = page_cache[req]

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/cache.py", line 89, in __getitem__
    return self._checkitem(name)[2]

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/cache.py", line 131, in _checkitem
    value = self.build(key, name, opened, entry)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 86, in build
    return ModuleCache.build(self, key, req, opened, entry)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/cache.py", line 380, in build
    exec(opened_as_str, module.__dict__)

  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi.py", line 112, in run
    sock = self._setupSocket()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 997, in _setupSocket
    req.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 572, in run
    self._end(appStatus, protocolStatus)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 601, in _end
    sys.exit(appStatus)

SystemExit: 0
```

A hint could be that it occurs only when I'm running it through Apache. In command line it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to run a WSGI app, via FCGI, but using mod_python. If you must use FCGI, you need to use mod_fastcgi. However, really you should be using mod_wsgi on its own without either that or flup.